# Does a character know they ate poison if they pass a fortitude save?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, saving-throw, poison

Player just ate some poisoned food. They passed their fortitude save. Does the character know that they just ate poison? Would they reach for a second bite?

Comment: Just to be sure this is the right question, are you thinking that they'd get poisoned again for every bite they eat?

Comment: I assume the player doesn't have any ranks in Craft (alchemy)? Because if they have any experience with poisons, I think it's pretty reasonable that they could figure it out.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Identifying a poison from its symptoms could be covered by several skills including Craft (alchemy), Knowledge (nature), or Heal. However, I think the question here is whether they have symptoms at all, since the poison has not yet caused any damage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From *Rules Compendium*

> ## Saving Throws
>
> #### Success and Failure
>
> A creature that successfully saves against an effect that has no obvious physical repercussions feels a hostile force or a tingle, but can’t deduce the exact nature of the attack.

So yes, someone who passes their Fortitude saving throw should know there was something “off” about the food, though they do not learn anything more than that, so they wouldn’t necessarily know if it had specifically been poisoned, much less with which poison.

This is a general rule, and it’s possible that a particular poison would indicate otherwise. However, unless the poison in question explicitly says so, the default is that someone can tell.

Comment: (Note that it's only the *RC* that allows information on any successful saving throw (as well as allowing folks to voluntarily fail any saving throw). The core rules (*PH* 177 and [here](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#saving-throw)) limit this to only spells, and, by extension, maybe spell-like abilities and supernatural abilities.)

Comment: I agree with this answer but the way its worded now makes me wonder if someone was taking a bite of food and got charmed and made their save, would know it was poison.